# English translation to First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have to create a scenario using FOL and i am having confusions for this particular sentence.

Sentence: 9.    If someone gets a seat in engineering, he will not get a seat in CS.

Which of the following FOL are correct to represent the above sentence?

∃x (get(x,EngSeat) --> ¬ get(x,CSseat))

∃x (get(x,EngSeat) ∧ ¬ get(x,CSseat))

Also, i replace 'someone' by 'anyone' in the above sentence,
should i replace  ∃x by ∀ x?

Comment: The first one with $\forall x$ instead of $\exists x$. Also $\forall x,(\neg A\lor \neg B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are the two get-statements respectively would be good.

Comment: In this context "someone" stands for a "generic" one.

Comment: @Gae.S.Thank you so much for the reply. But why should i negate both statements in this case? ∀ x (¬A V ¬b) means anyone who do not get a seat in engineering do not get a seat in cs. Will be grateful if you elaborate.

Comment: @3.00AMCoder It's because $\neg A\lor\neg B\equiv A\to\neg B$

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct. The correct translation is:

$~~~~~~\forall x: [Student(x) \implies [Gets(x, EngSeat) \implies \neg Gets(x, CSSeat)]]$

**Edit:** Where $Student$ is a unary predicate, $Gets$ is a binary predicate, $x$ is a bound variable, and both $EngSeat$ and $CSSeat$ are free variables.

**Edit:** Equivalently and perhaps more natural:

$~~~~~~\forall x: [Student(x) \implies \neg [Gets(x, EngSeat) \land Gets(x, CSSeat)]]$

Comment: What you are describing is not FOL, as the argument values are predicates themselves.

Comment: @Qwaster To clarify, the predicates are $Student$ and $Gets$. The variables are $x, EngSeat$ and $CSSeat$.